# Javascript/Moment - Issue with generating time slots

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to generate time slots with a gap of 15min between each one, like the following :

`["15:30", "15:45", "16:00", "16:15"...]`

So far, I managed to make it. However, if the current time is `15:25` (just an example) the generated array will start from `15:30` what I need instead (in this case) to generate time slots starting from `16:00` meaning that only the first time slot should be approximately away `30 min` from the current time.

Currently, I have the following code :

```
//Used momentJS library
function getTimeStops(end) {
  var roundedUp, startTime, endTime, timeStops;
  roundedUp = Math.ceil(moment().utc().minute() / 30) * 30;
  startTime = moment().utc().set({
    minute: roundedUp
  });
  endTime = moment(end, 'HH:mm');

  if (endTime.isBefore(startTime)) {
    endTime.add(1, 'day');
  }

  timeStops = [];

  while (startTime <= endTime) {
    timeStops.push(new moment(startTime).format('HH:mm'));
    startTime.add(15, 'minutes');
  }
  return timeStops;
}

var timeStops = getTimeStops('02:00');
console.log('timeStops ', timeStops);
```

Comment: I've updated my answer - misinterpreted the question 1st time round

Answer (score 0):

You're rounding to the nearest half hour here:

```
roundedUp = Math.ceil(moment().utc().minute() / 30) * 30;
```

Round to the nearest hour instead:

```
roundedUp = Math.ceil(moment().utc().minute() / 60) * 60;
```

Edit: just realised that the above is wrong and doesn't actually answer your question.

You do need to change your `roundedUp` value though.

What you need to do is:

1. Add 30 minutes to the current time
2. Round it to the closest 15 minute interval

That way - at most - you'll be 7.5 minutes out.

So for step 1, add 30 minutes

```
var add30mins = moment.utc().add(30, 'minutes')
```

Now we need to find the closest 15 minute interval.

```
var roundTo15Mins = Math.round(add30Mins.minute() / 15) * 15;
```

Then you can plug that into your startTime.

HTH

Comment: Can you give me an example of how it doesn't return the wanted results?